# this.app.service(...).create(...) is not a function

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I tried to make api request twice and the first one work, but the second fails with below error.

```
{
    "name": "GeneralError",
    "message": "this.app.service(...).create(...) is not a function",
    "code": 500,
    "className": "general-error",
    "data": {},
    "errors": {}
}
```

result.class.js

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
const errors = require('@feathersjs/errors');

exports.Submission = class Submission {
  constructor (options, app) {
    this.app = app;
  }

  async create (data, params) {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      return Promise.all(data.map(current => this.create(current, params)));
    }

    let result = await this.app.service('result').create({ //<------------- It works
      sectionId: data.sectionId,
    })
    console.log(result) // <------------------------------------ able to show the value
    (data.sub_sections).map(async sub_section =>{
      (sub_section.questions).map(async question =>{
        let payload = {
          answerId: question.questionId
        }
        await this.app.service('result').create(payload) //<------------- It results in error 
      })
    })
    return data;
  }

};
```

Comment: Can you share the code for service ?

Comment: where are you using Submission?? console `this.app` and see what are you getting??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem that it is the second call of `this.app.service().create()` that is causing the error you're seeing.

I am guessing the specific error message reported occurs when you do not have the `console.log()` statement in there. This is because of a missing semi-colon.

```
let result = await this.app.service('result').create({ 
  sectionId: data.sectionId,
}) // no semi-colon here
(data.sub_sections).map(//..)
```

JavaScript only treats a line break as a semicolon - ie an end of statement - if the next nonspace character cannot be interpreted as a continuation of the current statement. But in this case, it can - as an invocation of the result of the preceding `await` expression.

Note that when inserting the `console.log()` statement in between, you should encounter a similar issue:

```
console.log(...) is not a function
```

So just add a semi colon manually in this case.